# Change CSS on page resize

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, resize

I put this code together...

```
<title>Style Change on Resize</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function resize() {

if (screen.width <= 640)

{document.write("<link href='style1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")}

else

{document.write("<link href='style2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")}
}

</script>
</head>

<body onResize="resize();">

<div id="styleMe">This is a test of a resize javascirpt that will change its CSS sheet    
when the browser window is resized, or when being viewed on a mobile device, such as     
iOS, etc. Hello.</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and the CSS files just have this in them (with just a different background colour so i can see if its changing the CSS sheet)...

```
#styleMe {
background-color:#309;
height:200px;
width:100%;
}
```

The problem is when i run the page there's no styling on the words, then when i resize the page it just goes black, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you need to call resize on page load otherwise until you actually resize the function wont be called.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with [mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) using CSS only.

```
#styleMe {
  background-color:#309;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

  #styleMe {
    background-color: magenta;
  }

}
```

Comment: Need to be careful as this is CSS3, not supported by some older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should learn how to do responsive Web design, css3 media query is useful

Comment: responsive web design is not always possible just using css, even with css3.  Some of the more complex styling on my current project, I have to use javascript.  I agree with looking into things like media query, however you need to be careful about support for older browsers.